# Problems with token issuer when running OpenIddict as a container

Tags: docker, .net-core, docker-compose, openiddict

I'm trying to run OpenIddict in Docker together with an Api, the Api communicates with the OppenIddict application through a defined link in docker-compose (`api` -> `login`). I have a frontend application running outside of Docker accessing the Api and Login over `localhost`-addresses. Everything works fine until the point where the Api communicates with the Login application using the linked address (`login`), the problem then is that the issuer of the token doesn't match.
The issuer is in this case `http://localhost:4000` and it's expecting `http://login` when OpenIddict is validating the token.

I've tried to change the issuer in `Startup` and the `OpenIddictServerBuilder`, the problem then is that it changes the base address used in the discovery document resulting in the frontend trying to connect to `http://login`.

One potential solution to this is to change the hosts file and set a network redirect (redirecting `login` to `127.0.1.1` and setting the network redirect to use localhost:4000), but this feels like a too complex solution.

I've had similar issues with `IdentityServer4`, but there you can change the issuer without affecting the base address.

Hope that I explain the issue well enough, any ideas is really appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally figured it out, you can specify a list of valid issuers during the configuration of the OpenIddict server in `Startup`. Here I can say that `http://localhost:4000` is a valid issuer and therefore the token will be valid when the Api validates it even though it is communicating using a different address. I did it like this if it helps anyone in the future:

```cs
services.AddOpenIddict()
  .AddCore()
  .AddServer(builder =>
  {
    builder.Configure(options =>
    {
      options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidIssuers = new List<string>
      {
        "http://localhost:4000/",
      };
    });
  });
```

Comment: Thanks, do you also use this configuration for a production env,  when behind nginx you have one public address and services access by internal addresses.

Comment: @Eldar I see no reason why not

Comment: Wow, three days it took me to find this post. I was focusing on the singing keys not being validated correctly or something. Then I realized my docker compose environment was messing it up, and I couldn't figure out how to allow multiple issuers. Thanks a lot!